# Generate function and global variables

Tags: c, sqlite, macros, c-preprocessor

I wonder if there is a way to use **C** preprocessor for something like this. I have a code with a large number of SQL statements that I would like to prepare on the startup and then only keep global variables. I am trying to figure out a way to write a macro that would transform:

```
PREPARE_SQL (statement1_var, "SQL QUERY 1")
PREPARE_SQL (statement2_var, "SQL QUERY 2")
```

into:

```
static sqlite3_stmt * statement1_var;
static sqlite3_stmt * statement2_var;

static int prepare_statements(sqlite3 * db) {
    int result;

    result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SQL QUERY 1", -1, &statement1_var, NULL);
    if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
        return result;
    }
    result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SQL QUERY 2", -1, &statement2_var, NULL);
    if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
        return result;
    }
    return SQLITE_OK;
}
```

Comment: Preprocessing is only done before compiling. Am I misunderstanding your intentions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the X macro technique, first define your list using a non yet defined macro PREPARE_SQL

```
#define LIST_OF_ENTRIES                       \
PREPARE_SQL (statement1_var, "SQL QUERY 1")   \
PREPARE_SQL (statement2_var, "SQL QUERY 2")
```

Then define PREPARE_SQL for declaring variables, invoke your list macro, then undefine PREPARE_SQL again

```
#define PREPARE_SQL( var, text ) static sqlite3_stmt * var;
LIST_OF_ENTRIES        // invoke the macro that contains the list
#undef PREPARE_SQL
```

Then later, redefine PREPARE_SQL differently again, and invoke the same list macro...

```
static int prepare_statements(sqlite3 * db) {
    int result;

#define PREPARE_SQL(var, text)                               \
    result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, text, -1, &var, NULL);   \
    if (result != SQLITE_OK) {                               \
        return result;                                       \
    }
    LIST_OF_ENTRIES   // invoke the macro that contains the list
#undef PREPARE_SQL

    return SQLITE_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach.  It requires two macros but I think it's close to what you want.

The macros:

```
#define PREPARE_SQL_DECLARATION(V) static sqlite3_stmt *(V);

#define PREPARE_SQL(V,Q) \
    do { \
        int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, (Q), -1, &(V), NULL); \
        if (result != SQLITE_OK) \
            return result; \
    } while(0);
```

Example usage of the macros (e.g. `source.c`)

```
PREPARE_SQL_DECLARATION(statement1_var);
PREPARE_SQL_DECLARATION(statement2_var);
PREPARE_SQL_DECLARATION(statement3_var);

static int prepare_statements(sqlite3 * db) {
    PREPARE_SQL(statement1_var, "SQL QUERY 1");
    PREPARE_SQL(statement2_var, "SQL QUERY 2");
    PREPARE_SQL(statement3_var, "SQL QUERY 3");
    return SQLITE_OK;
}
```

Here is the output from the macro expansion (e.g. `gcc -E source.c`)

```
static sqlite3_stmt *(statement1_var);;
static sqlite3_stmt *(statement2_var);;
static sqlite3_stmt *(statement3_var);;

static int prepare_statements(sqlite3 * db) {
    do { int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, ("SQL QUERY 1"), -1, &(statement1_var), 0); if (result != 0) return result; } while(0);;
    do { int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, ("SQL QUERY 2"), -1, &(statement2_var), 0); if (result != 0) return result; } while(0);;
    do { int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, ("SQL QUERY 3"), -1, &(statement3_var), 0); if (result != 0) return result; } while(0);;
    return 0;
}
```

The `do { ... } while (0);` wrapping the code in the macro is one way for each statement expansion and execution to have its own `int result` within scope to return, but without interfering with later variables of the same name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach has exactly the issue I was trying to avoid - e.g. having to maintain 2 lists of statements with them getting out of sync causing a major headache. The other answer had only one list, I used that approach. Thanks!